# Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage

Tags: ios, swift

Upgrading to swift 1.2 prevents me from compiling. Error do not show inside the files, but it's a general compilation error message.

Logging the compilation text, i'm able to spot this error on a specific file:

```
Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage! 
invalid  linkage type for function declaration
LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!
```

Here is the content of the file, do you know what causes the error:

```
import Foundation

class appDisabled {
    func check(currentViewController: UIViewController, isLoginScreen: Bool) {

        var disabledStatus: Bool? {
            didSet {
                if let result = disabledStatus {
                    if result == true && isLoginScreen == false{
                            currentViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindToLoginScreen", sender: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        PFConfig.getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (config: PFConfig!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                disabledStatus = config["appDisabled"] as? Bool
                if disabledStatus! == true  {
                    appStatus.isAppDisabled = true
                } else {
                    appStatus.isAppDisabled = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Removing the second function block PFConfig.getConfigInBackgroundWithBlock... does allow the compilation to pass, so i'm not sure if it's that block itself that causes the problem, or the relation with the variable observer above.
Do you see any part of this code that could trigger the compiler error ?

Comment: Just to be clear, what exactly is your question?

Comment: I updated the post to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the line causing this problem is:

`if disabledStatus! == true {`

It appears they is a bug in Swift in accessing local variables in closures

https://gist.github.com/NeoTeo/545128f724cd47d84ee1

Here's a simplified test case:

```
func immediateFunction(function: () -> ()) {
    function()
}

class myClass {
    func check() {
        var disabledState: Bool? {
            didSet {
                println("Did set")
            }
        }

        immediateFunction() {
            disabledState = true

            if disabledState! == true {
                println("Not crashing anymore")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right it's specifically  that line of the code that cause the issue.

Comment: It appears that the didSet is causing the problem. Removing that seems to work for me.

Comment: I moved the entire var disabledStatus inside the closure  just after void in and it seems to work. Do you see any reason not to do so ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are using disabledState for in this case. It doesn't really seem necessary.

Comment: I had this while using an @Published array of protocols. Going off of bjtitus's suggestion of didSet causing the issue I found a workaround by using append instead.